# Rewrite URL using .htaccess not working in php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i need to rewrite this url "http://www.domain.com/admin/web/app_dev.php" to "http://www.domain.com/admin/"

**Here is my current htaccess**

Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

```
# Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
RewriteRule ^/admin/web/app_dev.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^/admin/web/app.php - [L]

# Fix the bundles folder
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /admin/web/api/$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^cron/(.*)$ /admin/web/cron/$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^bundles/(.*)$ /admin/web/bundles/$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ /admin/web/css/$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ /admin/web/js/$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^img/(.*)$ /admin/web/img/$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fonts/(.*)$ /admin/web/fonts/$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ /admin/web/uploads/$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^plugins/(.*)$ /admin/web/plugins/$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^font-awesome/(.*)$ /admin/web/font-awesome/$1  [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Change below before deploying to production
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin/web/app.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin/web/app_dev.php [QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^/admin/(.*) /admin/web/
RewriteRule ^/admin/?$ /admin/web/ [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```